# Error: Too many positional arguments (1) when using BLAST w/ a bash for loop

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, blast, ncbi

I'm trying to write a script that will go through all of the directories within a directory where it will query a specific sequence against a local blast database. I've run the BLAST search without the bash for loop and used a for loop to create the databases in the first place. I have tried everything suggested by others having this problem (where applicable) to no avail. I'm not copying and pasting anything, I've retyped the script and looked for stupid errors (of which I make plenty). Maybe I'm just not seeing it? Anyway here's the code:

```
SRV01:~$ for d in ~/data/Shen_transcriptomes/transcriptomes/*/; do tblastn -query ~/data/chitin_binding_protein/cbp_Tectaria_macrodonta.fa -db "$d"*BLASTdb* -out "$(basename "$d")".out; done
```

When I run the same thing with: `echo "$d"*BLASTdb*`, it returns the correct files. So the for loop seems to be working but the above script returns:

```
Error: Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: /home/dwickell/data/Shen_transcriptomes/transcriptomes/Acrostichum_aureum_RS90/RS_90_BLASTdb.nin
```

for every BLASTdb file in the directory.

-edit-

So this works, but I don't know enough about bash to understand why:

```
SRV01:~/data$ for d in /home/dwickell/data/Shen_transcriptome/transcriptomes/*/*.nin; do 
    name=$(echo "$d" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
    blastn -query ./chitin_binding_protein/cbp_Tectaria_macrodonta.fa -db "$name" -outfmt 6 -out RS_103_tblastn.out; done
```

Comment: `-db` takes a single argument. What is `-db "$d"*BLASTdb*` supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to query the local database in directory "$d". The idea is to be able to loop through multiple directories in .../transcriptomes/ to perform the same blast search on each one. "$d"*BLASTdb* is just the prefix of the db files.

Comment: Sure, but apparently you have multiple files matching `"$d"*BLASTdb*`. You can only specify one of them. (I don't know which one, I've never used BLAST.)

Comment: It takes a single argument but it's a file path plus a prefix, as a BLAST database is actually 6 files. So you have 6 files with the same prefix but a different extension located in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting you have a directory with more than one matching BLAST file. Try this test:

```
for d in ~/data/Shen_transcriptomes/transcriptomes/*/; do
  echo "For directory $d have:"
  ls -1 "$d"*BLASTdb*
  echo
done
```

Comment: So each directory has the typical 6 data files (.nhr, .nin, .nog, etc.) in addition to several fasta files that have a different prefix. The only strange thing that came up when I ran the above script is that the file permissions for one file: "RS_128_BLASTdb.nin" are different from all the rest (-rwxr-xr-x). For the record I have no idea what this means or why it would affect all the other directories.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so as I mentioned in the edit to my question above. I seem to have found a solution:

```
for d in /home/dwickell/data/Shen_transcriptomes/transcriptomes/*/*.nin; do 
    name=$(echo "$d" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
    blastn -query ./chitin_binding_protein/cbp_Tectaria_macrodonta.fa -db "$name" -outfmt 6 -out "$(basename "$d" .nin)".out; done
```

I'm not clear on why this works but it does. Perhaps it has something to do with the trailing asterisk in my earlier attempt? If anyone can clarify please do! However for my own purposes I consider this solved.

Thanks to everyone for commenting.

Comment: Instead of `"$name"` you can probably also just use `"${d%.nin}"`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks a bit cleaner that way at least!